# Getting rid of quotes in a string

Tags: java, string

Hi I have a string with quotation marks

```
String s = "\"hello\"";
```

and I was wondering how to get rid of the quotes in the string s. Is there a method that can get rid of a specific char? Something like s.getRidofChar(");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

The `\` is because we have to escape the quotes.  This is saying we will replace all instances of quotes with the empty string.  Remember that `String` is immutable, so we need to assign the value returned by `replaceAll` back to `s` (or some other variable).

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "\"hello\"";
s = s.replaceAll("\"","")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Try [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: This won't work -- replace() will only replace one character with another.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.replaceAll() with an empty replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a certain character at a certain position, take the substring before and after the character and join them together.